# PHP Variable from one page to automatically run SQL query on other page

Tags: php, sql-server

I am currently trying to pass a variable from one page to another then load the query on that page with the passed variable.

My code is as follows:

**Awaiting Variable**

```
if(isset($_POST['viewrecord'])){
    $sup_code = $_POST['vhidden'];
}
```

**SQL Query**

```
$sql = "SELECT     sup_code, firstname, lastname, email, telephone
FROM         dbo.table
WHERE sup_code = ('$sup_code')";
```

Comment: Can you post code from both page? Are you using POST method to pass the variable?

Comment: I am using post yes, it's a strange one.

Comment: Can you post code from both page plz?

Comment: I can see the variable is taking effect as I have echo'd the result on the second page.

Comment: echo '<form action=support-record.php method=post>';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="vhidden" value=" ';               echo $row['PRCODE'];              echo ' " >';               echo '<input class=form-control id=input-Default type=submit name=viewrecord value=View>';             echo '</form>';

Comment: just a table in the database which contains the given variable in one of the columns. 

The variable being passed would be something like SUP-01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, I added the following to the variable on page 2 and this seemed to solve the issue.

```
$sup_code = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $_POST['vhidden']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['viewrecord'])){
    $sup_code = $_POST['vhidden'];
}
$_SESSION["sup_code"] = $sup_code;
```

SQL Query

```
$sql = "SELECT     sup_code, firstname, lastname, email, telephone
FROM         dbo.table
WHERE sup_code = '".$_SESSION["sup_code"]."'";
```

Comment: If you need to pass a php variable  from one page to another, create  a session variable.